# How to take the output of a BAT file and save it to a string

Tags: c#, batch-file, cmd

I have a BAT file that I am running using the following code:

```
@ECHO ON
java com.mypackage.test send
```

which result in this:

```
C:\myfolder>java com.mypackage.test send
EXEC Sending...
Received 1 response(s)
Status Code: C00
```

How do I take the `Status Code` value (`C00`) and save it to a string in my WinForm C# application so I can use it for other actions?

I set the..

`proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;`

but not sure what to do next...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of reading a directory listing. Of course it is relatively easy to change for your requirements.

```
void Main()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var pSpawn = new Process
    {
         StartInfo = 
         { 
            WorkingDirectory = @"D:\temp", 
            FileName = "cmd.exe", 
            Arguments ="/c dir /b", 
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false
         }
    };


    pSpawn.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
    pSpawn.Start();
    pSpawn.BeginOutputReadLine();
    pSpawn.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
proc.Start();    // Start the proccess
proc.WaitForExit();
var stream = proc.StandardOutput;
```

the [Process.StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a StreamReader, which you then can read line by line with the [ReadLine method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader.readline). You can then parse for the desired output

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an output and don't care to code this in C#, just modify your batch file to send the output to `output.log`:

```
@ECHO ON
java com.mypackage.test send > output.log
```

Your application can then open and process the log file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think "save it to a string in my WinForm C# application" is pretty clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
//create the process
Process p = new Process();

//redirect the output stream
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "myfile.bat";
p.Start();

//read the output stream
string statusCode = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```